# Crackling in Camtasia Studio with Scarlett

Tags: audio-recording

I am using my Scarlett 2i4 to record inside Camtasia. Everything was fine for a while, but now I get an annoying popping noise all the time. Only happens with the 2i4, my lifecam is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the power to the 2i4 was in a low-power USB slot. I moved the plug to the 3x USB Power slot and everything works just fine.